# date between query issue in sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite

In my data base , i was stored one student data in the following date format is 07-03-2013(dd-mm-yyyy). For example the start date greater than the end date ,no row return in the results.

For Ex.

select student_name from general_details where join_date between '11-02-2013' and '08-03-2013'

it returns 0

if start date less than the end  date

select student_name from general_details where join_date between '01-02-2013' and '08-03-2013'

it returns row value 1;

Please suggest ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The dates are compared alphabetically and not as datetime stamps.

If you can influence how the dates are stored, use a format such as ISO-8601 `yyyy-MM-dd` or unix epoc timestamps to make the comparisons work.

If you cannot influence the data, you can convert the values in SQL by picking up the components with `substr()` and concatenating together with `||`, like this:

```
substr(join_date,7,4) || substr(join_date,4,2) || substr(join_date,1,2)
```